# SimpleSAML metadata converter

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I use the library simpleSAMLPhp to develop a service provider.

My problem is that I have a `saml token xml` generated by an Identity provider but I can't actually access the identity provider (problem of security)

I tried to use the simpleSAML metadata converter of the library but when I do this I have a error at the first line :

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
1 C:\wamp\www\var\simplesamlphp\www\_include.php:37 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Unexpected root node: [urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol]:Response
Backtrace:
2 C:\wamp\www\var\simplesamlphp\lib\SimpleSAML\Metadata\SAMLParser.php:305 (SimpleSAML_Metadata_SAMLParser::parseDescriptorsElement)
1 C:\wamp\www\var\simplesamlphp\lib\SimpleSAML\Metadata\SAMLParser.php:281 (SimpleSAML_Metadata_SAMLParser::parseDescriptorsString)
0 C:\wamp\www\var\simplesamlphp\www\admin\metadata-converter.php:11 (N/A)
```

How can I resolve this error?
How can I begin the development if I can't access to the service provider?